# where is login bash script or ~/.profile MAC

Tags: macos, bash

I want to install a package and in the README it says:

```
Add the following line to your login bash script (e.g., ~/.profile)
```

I cannot find any of them on my mac, where are they located?

Comment: You might need to create them. They don't necessarily exist by default.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? If they exist where they could be located?Tnx

Comment: `~/.profile` is a literal path that might be of use. You can type that in to your terminal directly (e.g. `ls ~/.profile`)

Comment: `~` means "my home directory" in bash, if that isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bash reads only `/etc/bashrc` at startup on mac, but you can (and should) go ahead and create `~/.profile` with whatever commands you need, and your bash session will read it at startup.

As you might expect, files in `/etc/` will be executed for every user starting a bash session, whereas files in `~/` will be executed only for you.

This excellent guide explains:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html